# Inserir valor de foreach em uma variável

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando sem sucesso criar uma variável com as variáveis do foreach para inserção em banco, os valores são de checkbox marcados, estou tentando dessa forma:

```
        // buscando os produtos             
        foreach ($_REQUEST['produto'] as $value) {

            $rel0[0] = $value[0];
            $rel1[1] = $value[1];
            $rel2[2] = $value[2];   
            $rel3[3] = $value[3];
            $rel4[4] = $value[4];
            $rel5[5] = $value[5];
            $rel6[6] = $value[6];
            $rel7[7] = $value[7];
            $rel8[8] = $value[8];
            $rel9[9] = $value[9];   

        }
```

Para inserir no banco estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
        // inserindo os produtos no banco de dados
        mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);       
        $sql = "INSERT INTO relacionamento ( id_produto, id_departamento, rel0, rel1, rel2, rel3, rel4, rel5, rel6, rel7, rel8, rel9 ) values ( '$produto', '$id_departamento', '$rel0[0]', '$rel1[1]', '$rel2[2]', '$rel3[3]', '$rel4[4]', '$rel5[5]', '$rel6[6]', '$rel7[7]', '$rel8[8]', '$rel9[9]' )";
        $queryExec = mysql_query($sql, $conexao) or die("Erro ao inserir relacionamento no banco de dados.");
```

Os checkbox estão assim:

```
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="produto[]" id="produto[]" value="<?php echo $row_produtos['id_produto']; ?>" />
          <?php echo $row_produtos['id_produto']; ?></td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: E o checkbox? mostra ele aí pra gente!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amigo, você está criando 10 arrays sem necessidade. Coloque todos com o mesmo nome da variável, alterando apenas o índice. Outra coisa, o `foreach` serve justamente para percorrer o array, você não deve colocar todos os values desta forma.

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['produto'] as $value) {
    $rel[] = $value;
}
```

Lembre de alterar também na sua query. As variáveis $rel0[0], $rel1[1]... devem ficar $rel[0], $rel[1]...

Comment: eu também tinha pensado nisso. Por isso pedi pra mostrar como é que estava o checkbox, rsrsrs

Comment: Fantástico, obrigado @Oeslei e Wallace Maxters, foi de grande ajuda.